# How can I add a same table name but different schema in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, database-schema

I have a situation where I need to create a new table in a separate schema through EntityFramework that has the same table name in a different schema.

How can this be done through EntityFramework?  I am currently locked to EntityFramework 5.0.4, so I cannot move on to EntityFramework 6.

Existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA ( /*table contents*/ );
```

New table:

```
CREATE TABLE AnotherSchema.TableA ( /*table contents*/ );
```

I believe I have already created the POCO classes correctly, and MigrationBuilder's `Up()` and `Down()` methods explicitly use the schema names:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(name: "AnotherSchema");
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(schema: "AnotherSchema", name: "TableA", ...);
    // ...
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(schema: "AnotherSchema", name: "TableA");
}
```

However, when I execute `Update-Database` I get the following error:

```
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration 'xxxxxxxxxx'.
Failed executing DbCommand (55ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AnotherSchema].[TableA] (
    /*table contents*/
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'TableA' in the database.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:xxxxxxxx
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'TableA' in the database.
PM>
```

Comment: Why are you CREATE TABLE every time application starts?  create table should only be used when the table doesn't exist.

Comment: The log indicates EF is trying to create the table in the other schema.  Are you sure it's not already there?

Comment: @jdweng I am trying to execute the CREATE TABLE as a one-off, not every time the application starts up.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have a SSMS open and can see that the new table indeed does not yet exist; the only table that does exist is in the other schema.  I also validated with a direct query to sys.tables (in case SSMS UI wasn't refreshing properly).

Comment: Then you need to check if table exists.  Maybe use GetSchema to see if table is in database.

Comment: This can be disregarded as a hidden copy-paste error was found to be the cause.